# Workflow 2013 not working in some subsites

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

I have an issue where 2013 workflows aren't able to be run on some subsites. On other subsites I have no issue to publish and run the workflow. For the subsite where the workflow is not working, I can still publish the workflow with no errors but the workflows did not appear in the associated list. I have compared the features and permission and they are all configured the same. I noticed that on the subsite where it's not working, the subsite contains some customized lists and tasks list that was not on subsites with working workflows. Anyone have any ideas on what setting could cause the workflow not able to work in some subsites?

Answer (score 0):

Please troubleshoot this issue as following:

1. Go to Sharepoint Designer ->Navigation -> All Files -> Workflows -> Workflowname -> check if the *.xoml and *.xsn files are not checked in.
2. [Clear SharePoint Designer Cache](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33469.how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache.aspx)
3. Check if there are required fields.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I checked in SPD and the workflow itself is not found under SPD > Navigation > All Files > Workflows. I also already cleared the SPD cache but to no avail.